# Socket.io: Does emitting messages send all data to all clients?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Question is geared towards understanding how **socket.io** works.

If I have a server with multiple clients and the following function (pseudocode):

```
// Server-side
socket.emit('data-request', { some large object });
```

Does the server send the large data object to each of the clients or does it only send to clients that have a corresponding (function / event) ?

```
socket.on('data-request', function(data){blah blah blah});
```

Comment: I wish I could give multiple "right" answers. I've selected the answer that provided the most help for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, what you're doing there would send a message to every single socket that is connected to the **server**, except the socket that is `socket`, if you want to broadcast to a specific room you would do

```
 io.sockets.in('some room name').broadcast('some data')
```

if you want to broadcast to everyone in a specific room except the sender if the sender is in that room you would do

```
 socket.broadcast.to('some room name').emit('some data');
```

First of all though you would probably need to create some rooms, in which case you would just do

```
someSocket.join('some room name')
```

Maybe something like this would help you out.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   // let everyone know i'm here
   socket.broadcast.emit('user connected');

   socket.on('join-data-request-room', function(){
       socket.join('data-request-room')
   })
});
```

Now you could do this

```
 io.sockets.in('data-request-room').broadcast('new data')
```

and it would send to each in that room, there are currently no one in that room, to add people in that room you would do something like this on the client **(browser)**.

```
 io.emit('join-data-request-room')
```

Now and only now will that **"client"** be in the room `data-request-room`

I haven't used **socket.io** in months so there may be some better ways I don't know.

Comment: Can a socket belong to multiple rooms at once?

Comment: @GoldfishGrenade I'm pretty sure they can. Try it.

Comment: @GoldfishGrenade Yeah, sure.

Answer (score 1):

The message will be sent to only the socket who is listening. The socket connection means you get one to one connection between server and client.

If you want to broadcast the same message to all the clients (except yourself):

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.broadcast.emit('user connected');
});
```

The broadcast gets called like [this](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L126), and the implementation is in the [adapter module](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-adapter/blob/master/index.js#L98).

If you require more specific message sending you could use the room concept, read more about [rooms](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms).

Comment: This seems unlikely to me. How does the server know who's listening to what? Is there some sort of handshake protocol? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @acbabis It broadcasts to every single socket that is connected to the server, -@jurka **except the socket that was connected**, The server knows what sockets are connected, In this situation they are all listening on the **"global scope"** if that's what you would call it, there is no rooms or namespaces involved here.

Comment: Yes there is handshake procedure also https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing#handshaking

Comment: I know that. I'm asking whether the server knows if the client has subscribed to a certain message type. That's how I interpret the OP's question.

Comment: Yes, I am asking about how/if the server know what messages the clients are subscribed to.

Comment: Seems like you need to look at the room concept, but be aware that all of this is not persistent.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that the server has no way of knowing who is listening to what message types, but I'm not 100% certain, and I will continue to look for a reference. In the meantime, if you want to send to only certain clients, you should use [rooms](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms).

**EDIT:**

This simple experiment should give the answer:

```
//Server-side
socket.emit('data-request', { a: 100 });
...
//Client-side
socket.on('message', function(data){console.log(data)});
```

Listen for all messages. The client should receive the `data-request` message.

**EDIT 2:** Disregard my example code. It doesn't work.

Comment: Very interesting. I will definitely look into rooms.

Comment: Unless `"message"` is used by socket.io this wouldn't work. is `"message"` a built in event?

Comment: I thought `message` was used as a global handle. I guess I was mistaken.

Comment: Maybe you meant 'message' without quotes?